# CanCan and polymorphic associations (Eager Loading error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cancan

I'm trying to define a user's ability to access something based on a column on an associated model (so something like `can :read, Step, 'steppable' => {published: true}`), the problem is that it's a polymorphic association so it can't find the steppable table because it doesn't exist.

I've got steps, and each step has a steppable (either a lecture, a quiz, or some other action). I need an activerecord query that will work. I've tried:

`Step.includes(:steppable).where('steppable' => {published: true})`

and

`Step.joins(:steppable).where('steppable' => {published: true})`

But both result in `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :steppable`

Models look like this:

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   belongs_to :steppable, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
   ...
end
```

and

```
class Lecture
   ...
   has_one :step, as: :steppable, dependent: :destroy
   ...
end
```

**Note:** I'd like to be agnostic regarding the associated model, and in order for it to work for fetching records with CanCan, it has to be done using database columns (see [github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities))

Comment: Did you try `Step.includes(:steppable).all`, just to check? What does your models look like? We need more information...

Comment: Yeah, Step.includes(:steppable).all works but Step.includes(:steppable).where('steppable' => {published: true}).all leads to the same `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :steppable` error. I updated the question with info on the model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
can :read, Step, steppable_type: 'Lecture', steppable_id: Lecture.published.pluck(:id)
can :read, Step, steppable_type: 'OtherThing', steppable_id: OtherThing.published.pluck(:id)
```

You have to do it for each `Steppable` class, but it gets around the eager loading polymorphic associations problem. To dry this up a bit:

```
[Lecture, OtherThing].each do |klass|
  can :read, Step, steppable_type: klass.to_s, steppable_id: klass.published.pluck(:id)
end
```

In this case, as long as each `steppable` class has a scope `published`, you just add any `steppable` class into that array, even if `published` is defined differently in each class.

Comment: This example is too simple, you may want to define hash conditions on the steppable record which differ depending on the model and it will crash because CanCanCan will try to call an attribute which does not exist for that model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
lectures = Lecture.where(published: true)
steps = Step.where(steppable_type: 'Lecture', steppable_id: lectures)
```

Or in the case you really want to be agnostic regarding the associated model:

```
Step.all.select { |s| s.steppable.published? }
```

Comment: Neither of those will work. I'd like to be agnostic regarding the associated model, and in order for it to work for fetching records with CanCan, it has to be done using database columns (see https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities)

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you're trying to do with CanCan?

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to set something like: can :read, Step, steppable: {published: true} but that leads to the error above. I could do it with can :read, Step do |step| step.steppable.published? end but that doesn't allow for fetching items using CanCan's accessible_by method.

Comment: Then I guess I won't be able to help you more than I did ; )